# struct with a property of type DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a struct with a property of type DataTable.  I'm getting a error A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type `System.Reflection.RuntimeModule`.  I know it is throwing it because of the DataTable type.  What can I do to get pass this.  I'm trying to return the struct in a web method call.

```cs
public struct EnrollmentsJsonData 
{
    public DataTable dtEnrollments;
    public int LastRecord;
}

var dt = Enrollment.GetEnrollmentData(enrolledFilter, overdueFilter,
    expiredFilter, completedFilter, standaloneCourseFilter, standaloneILTFilter,
    learningPathFilter, certificationFilter, orderBy, qryLastRecord, out int
        outLastRecord);
outLastRecord);

EnrollmentsJsonData jsonData = new EnrollmentsJsonData 
{
    dtEnrollments = dt,
    intLastRecord = outLastRecord
};
    
return jsonData;
```

Comment: What version of ASP are you using? What is used for serialization? Are we talking about json serialization?

Comment: DataTables have always had serialization issues.  Can you show us some code (as a [mcve]); the verb _serializing_ can take many forms (XML serialization, binary serialization, the WCF serializer, JSON serialization...).  Why are you using a DataTable?

Comment: ASP.NET 4.7 and I'm not using any serialization.

Comment: Your first two sentences are _"I have a struct with a property of type DataTable. I'm getting a error A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'."_ You are going to need to give us some more info if you are getting a serialization error while not serializing

Comment: @NewbieCoder well, you say "in a web method call" - that usually implies serialization; what are you returning, and how? note: returning a `DataTable` in a web call is *usually* a bad idea

Comment: (sees edit) OK; and how are you populating that `DataTable`? I *repeat* the sending a `DataTable` over a web API seems unusual (especially for JSON) - it *may* be that you're going about this the wrong way, but without knowing what you're *actually trying to do*, we can't be sure on that

Comment: I'm getting enrollments for a course and it is coming back in a data table.  So I thought I'd pass that back after I got it.

Comment: Create a type (a class) that contains the information (as properties) you want to transfer to the client.  Copy the data from the DataTable to a `List<MyInformation>` and return that instead of the DataTable.  Or skip the DataTable and look at using Dapper.  DataTables were state-of-the-art in 2003.  They are too complicated for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Flydog57 thank you, your suggestion of using a List<> helped.

Comment: Well, in place of a struct, why not just create a class with the same properties and that data table. It should then serialize just fine. And you have the initialize event (new event) of that class in which you can setup + create the new instance of the datatable that you have in that class. Stucts are a shortcut - but they are only have limited functionality - really, beyond a few simple base variable types, then it time to create a class in place of a struct - once made, the code in both cases will and should be identical anyway.